# Random blogger posts background color from a predefined list of hex colors

Tags: javascript, blogger

My blog is http://nefelisdreams.blogspot.com/

and i have found this piece of code which randomly changes posts background color from all hex values

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 14)];
    }
    return color;
    }
    $(function() {
    $(".post").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", get_random_color());
    });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>

also found this code which uses predefined hex values to randomly choose from

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var colors = ["#556270","#00adf3","#0e94ec","#81d8d0","#fa023c","#a66c9d","#ffcc00","#cf3140"];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
    $('.title').css("color", colors[rand]);
    });
</script>
```

I want to combine these codes so that i can randomly alter each post background color from a predetermined list of colors

thanks in advance

Comment: then go for it. what have you tried already?

Comment: i am not a developer and tried with no avail

Comment: some of these links should do https://duckduckgo.com/?q=learn+to+code+in+javascript

Comment: here is my most promising attempt

<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function get_random_color() {
    var colors = ["#556270","#00adf3","#0e94ec","#81d8d0","#fa023c","#a66c9d","#ffcc00","#cf3140"];
    color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    }
    return color;
    }
    $(function() {
    $(".post").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", get_random_color());
    });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>